# c# The ConnectionString property has not been initialized

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I've been trying to create a migration and then update the database (using EF Core tools and SSMS to check the database). I've been struggling because I have different projects. The organization of my solution is the following:

[image]

I want to have the migration and the related DB interactions in `VSC.Repo`. This means that the context is in this project. Besides that, I have my connection string in the default appsettings, which is in `VSC.API` (different assembly). I've tried various ways of trying to get the connection string from there, but I always get the following error when I run the "dotnet ef database update" in the `VSC.Repo` project:

[image]

This is my context class:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{

    private readonly string connectionString;

    public DataContext()
    {
    }

    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options, IConfiguration configuration) : base(options)
    {
        connectionString = configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection").Value;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    }
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any help would me much appreciated.

EDIT: With the hardcoded string it works perfectly fine, but this is bad practice and I don't want to implement this way.

appsettings.json:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "server=localhost;database=vscDatabase;trusted_connection=true;TrustServerCertificate=True;"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
```

program.cs:

```
WebApplicationBuilder? builder = 
WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();

var connectionString = 
builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => 
options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
//builder.AddRepoConfigurations();

var app = builder.Build();
```

Comment: Try `configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")`

Comment: Still the same error...

Comment: Remove the parameterless constructor; wherever it's used, that instance has a null connection string. Or make sure the connection string is initialized no matter which constructor is used.

Comment: Also... shouldn't the parameterized constructor pass the connection string to the `base` constructor?

Comment: The base constructor only takes one parameter (the options), so I can't pass the connection string. As for the parameterless suggestion, whenever I remove it I get the error "Unable to create an object of type "DataContext", which is very strange.

Comment: @RandRandom I understand the problem, I just can't figure out the solution. If the string was populated I wouldn't get this error. As I mentioned in my edit, if I hardcode the string everything works smothly.

Comment: @MiguelFerreira what does `appsettings.json` contain? How do you construct the `DataContext` object? There shouldn't be any configuration code in the first place, or even a public default constructor. If you use .NET Core's dependency injection,  `AddDbContext` will register the DbContext *and* supply the config parameters. The DbContext itself won't have to know what database is used or even how the connection string is named

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I will edit the post and put the appsettings file as well as the startup. What you said make perfect sense and that was my first try. Since I have a different project (class library that contains the dbcontext and migrations) I tried to execute the command "dotnet ef update database" (on the class lib project) but got different errors. One of them I mentioned above and the other I get is "Unable to create an object of type DataContext". This last one happens when I tried the way you said, injecting the DataContext in startup.

Comment: So the real problem is EF migrations. The error you got  doesn't mean that `AddDbContext` doesn't work. By default `dotnet ef database update` will use the settings specified in `AddDbContext` but you can override them with the `--connectionstring` parameter. The command must be executed in the root project, ie wherever `Program.cs` or `Startup.cs` are.

Comment: Jesus, I just executed the command on the API (where program.cs is) and it worked. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so @Panagiotis Kanavos found out that I was executing the command in the wrong project, more precisely, in one that did not have the program.cs, and this was the issue. When I executed in the correct one, it worked just fine.

Comment: I make the same mistake every other week when I try to run `dotnet ef reverse` in the class project I want instead of the root project. Somehow I always forget I need to be in the root

Comment: If it happens again, I'll make sure I will try this approach in the first place! :)